# How do you test RawModules?

Tags: chisel

I'm using a chisel RawModule for an AXI interface to a module I'm building (so that I can use axi aclk and aresetn.)  However, I'm unable to do the normal tactic of using a peekpoke tester. What's the recommended strategy for testing rawmodules that have clocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PeekPokeTester`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/chisel-testers/SNAPSHOT/chisel3/iotesters/PeekPokeTester$.html) is currently limited to working on `MultiIOModule` or its subtypes. You can get around this by wrapping your `RawModule` in a `MultiIOModule` and bridging the IO (including the implicit clock/reset) from the wrapping `MultiIOModule` to your `RawModule`.

The new testing and verification library for Chisel (which replaces chisel-testers/`chisel3.iotesters`) is expected to support this natively and has an associated tracking issue: [ucb-bar/chisel-testers2#14](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2/issues/14).

**Edit: Example of wrapping a `RawModule` in a `MultiIOModule`**:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage

sealed trait CommonIO { this: RawModule =>
  val a = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val b = IO(Output(Bool()))
}

class Foo extends RawModule with CommonIO {
  val clk = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val rst = IO(Input(Reset()))
  b := withClockAndReset(clk, rst){ RegNext(a, true.B) }
}

class Wrapper extends MultiIOModule with CommonIO {
  val foo = Module(new Foo)
  foo.a := a
  b := foo.b
  foo.clk := clock
  foo.rst := reset
}

(new ChiselStage)
  .execute(Array("-X", "verilog"),
           Seq(chisel3.stage.ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new Wrapper)))
```

This produces the following FIRRTL:

```
circuit Wrapper :
  module Foo :
    input a : UInt<1>
    output b : UInt<1>
    input clk : Clock
    input rst : Reset

    reg _T : UInt<1>, clk with : (reset => (rst, UInt<1>("h01")))
    _T <= a
    b <= _T

  module Wrapper :
    input clock : Clock
    input reset : UInt<1>
    input a : UInt<1>
    output b : UInt<1>

    inst foo of Foo
    foo.a <= a
    b <= foo.b
    foo.clk <= clock
    foo.rst <= reset
```

Note:

1. The use of [`withClockAndReset`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/SNAPSHOT/chisel3/withClockAndReset$.html) to use `clk` and `rst` for the clock and reset connections of the `RegNext`
2. The connections from the implicit `Wrapper.clock` and `Wrapper.reset` have to be made explicitly. `withClockAndReset` will not work here.

Comment: Have you an example on how to wrap a RawModule for PeekPokeTester ? I'm trying it with my spi2wb project but can't manage my clock and reversed reset. https://github.com/Martoni/spi2wb/blob/master/src/main/scala/spi2wb.scala#L210

Comment: I updated my answer to include a small example of wrapping a RawModule in a MultiIOModule.